# For some reason I have to press shift+ctrl+] to look for a tag in vim

Tags: vim, ctags

I have my ctags setup correctly in vim, I used to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and it just worked as it should. But for some reason, it stopped working recently, maybe because of the installation of some unrelated plug-in.

Whats even more confusing is that if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> it jumps into the tag correctly, or if I use the command `tag` it also work. I've looked into `:map` and I didn't see any mapping that may be causing this. Any one have tips?

Comment: What happens when you execute `:verbose nmap <C-]>` in vim's command line?

Comment: Hey @Apitosu thanks for the reply. I solved the issue. It was just a bug in Karabiner-Elements (a plugin to override mac keys), and it kinda fixed itself. Not sure if I should just delete this post, as I don't think it will be useful for other people.

Comment: Never delete posts on SO after you've solved them, someone coming after you will appreciate the answer. :)

Comment: I understand that, but there is no useful answer here.